# landing page error in when sending form info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a landing page with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-27524997-1"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-27524997-1');
    </script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#f2e50d">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css?v=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/responsive.css?v=1" media="only screen and (max-width : 1000px)">
    <title>המרכז הדיגיטלי</title>
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
        !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s)
        {
            if (f.fbq)
                return;
            n = f.fbq = function () {
                n.callMethod ?
                        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments);
            };
            if (!f._fbq)
                f._fbq = n;
            n.push = n;
            n.loaded = !0;
            n.version = '2.0';
            n.queue = [];
            t = b.createElement(e);
            t.async = !0;
            t.src = v;
            s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
        }(window, document, 'script',
                'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq('init', '199994556862560');
        fbq('track', 'PageView');
    </script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

```
<header id="head" class="section">
    <img src="assets/images/header.jpg" class="full-width hide_mobile">
    <img src="assets/images/landing.jpg" class="full-width show_mobile">
    <a id="logo" href="/">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
    </a>
    <div id="contact" class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contact-box">
                <h3>רוצים לדעת עוד?<br> השאירו פרטים ונחזור אליכם
                    עם כל התשובות לכל השאלות</h3>
            </div>
            <form id="form">
                <div class="finputs">
                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="* שם">
                    <input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="* כתובת מייל">
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="* טלפון" >
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="מאשר" id="confirm" style=" width: 20px;" />מאשר הגעה לערב פתוח ב - 26.11.18</label>
                </div>
                <div id="imgform">
                     <button id="send">שלח</button>
                <img src="assets/images/contact_icon.png" class="contact_icon"> 
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<div id="what" class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <h1> מה נדרש כדי לבנות קריירה מקצועית בדיגיטל?</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="what-icon">
                    <img src="assets/images/what-i3.png">
                </div>
                <div class="what-block">
                    <h2>360 של ניהול קמפיינים ותוכן דיגיטלי</h2>
                    <p>מסלול לימודים מקיף 360 מעלות בו אתם מקבלים את  כל  <br>
                        הכלים שאתם צריכים כדי ליצור, לנהל ולנתח קמפיינים<br>
                        דיגיטליים ולכתוב כמו קופירייטרים מנוסים.<br>
                        הקורס שלנו כולל: 620 שעות אקדמיות; 8 חודשים<br>
                        2 מפגשים בשבוע 4 שעות כל מפגש
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="what-icon">
                    <img src="assets/images/what-i2.png">
                </div>
                <div class="what-block">
                    <h2>ביקוש גבוה לאנשי דיגיטל מקצועיים ומוכשרים</h2>
                    <p>
                        תחום הפרסום השיווק הדיגיטלי בישראל ובעולם, נמצא בתאוצה<br>
                        מטאורית. כל תחום בחיינו עובר דיגיטציה: פיננסים, טכנולוגיה,<br>
                        תקשורת, קולנוע, מסחר ועוד. מה שאומר שהביקוש לאנשי דיגיטל <br>
                        טובים עולה. האפשרויות שנפתחות בפני מי שנכנס לעולם הדיגיטל הן <br>
                        רבות, מאחר וכל הזמן ניתן להתפתח ולהתקדם הן מבחינה מקצועית והן <br>
                        מבחינה כלכלית. סיימתם את הקורס? אנחנו נדאג ללוות אתכם ולספק <br>
                        לכם הכוונה בין אם כשכירים או עצמאיים..

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50px" class="hide_mobile"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="what-icon">
                    <img src="assets/images/what-i1.png" style="position: relative;right: -15px">
                </div>
                <div class="what-block">
                    <h2>התנסות מעשית תוך כדי מסלול</h2>
                    <p>מסלול סטאז' ייחודי המפגיש אתכם עם לקוחות ומותגים <br>
                        אמיתיים, ויישום של הידע והכלים הנרכשים במהלך <br>
                        המסלול, תוך ליווי של מנטורים מקצועיים.<br>
                        הניסיון שתצברו בתוספת תיק העבודות המקצועי יהוו<br>
                        מקפצה מצוינת בדרך לפיתוח הקריירה המקצועית שלכם.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="what-icon">
                    <img src="assets/images/what-i4.png" style="position: relative;right: -10px">
                </div>
                <div class="what-block">
                    <h2>ללמוד אצל הטובים והמנוסים ביותר</h2>
                    <p>
                        עם למעלה מ- 10,000 בוגרים שהשתלבו בתפקידי מפתח בתעשיית <br>
                        השיווק והפרסום, ומאות חברות וארגונים שבחרו להכשיר את עובדיהם <br>
                        אצלנו בתוספת מרצים ומדריכים מהטובים והמנוסים בתחום הדיגיטל,<br>
                        כל זה הופך את המכללה לניו מדיה למקום שבו הקריירה שלכם <br>
                        בדיגיטל מתחיל. ואגב,<br> אנחנו פה לפני כולם- המכללה הוותיקה ביותר <br>
                        בתחום הדיגיטל בישראל!

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





    <div class="row" id="what2">


<div class="row col-md-12" id="content1">

        <div class="col-md-12">

               <h1>אז מה לומדים בתכלס?</h1>

               <p class="headp">הנה כמה טעימות מהקורס המקיף ביותר בישראל בתחום הדיגיטלי:</p>  

        </div>

</div>  

        <div class="row" id="inforow" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2 class="mobile">יסודות שיווק ואסטרטגיה דיגיטלית</h2>
       <p class="blocfix">
                    כל מה שצריך לדעת כדי לצאת לדרך - היכרות מעמיקה עם כל המושגים החשובים, יצירת אסטרטגיה שיווקית, ניתוח סביבת המותג ואפיון קהלי יעד לפרסום

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>יצירת תוכן וקופירייטינג פרסומי</h2>
                <p class="blocfix">
                    התוכן הוא המלך - כתיבת מאמרים מושלמים, פיתוח צורת חשיבה של קופירייטר מקצועי וקידום מותגים בעזרת מילים    
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>מיתוג, עיצוב וקריאייטיב</h2>
            <p class="blocfix">
                    ממתקים לעיניים - יצירת ספר מותג ושמירה על אחדות מיתוגית, היכרות עם תוכנות עיצוב אינטרנטיות וטרנדים בעולם העיצוב הדיגיטלי, עבודה מול מחלקות עיצוב ומיתוג והתאמת התוצר הגרפי לפלטפורמות השונות ברשת

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>קידום והפצה בדיגיטל</h2>
             <p class="blocfix">
                    מפייסבוק עד גוגל דרך ווטסאפ ואינסטה - סודות הפרסום הממומן והאורגני, עבודה נכונה עם תקציבי פרסום והיכרות מעמיקה עם כל סוגי הקמפיינים הדיגיטליים

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>מדידה וניתוח DATA</h2>
            <p class="blocfix">
                    מה זה שווה אם אי אפשר למדוד את זה - התנסות בעבודה עם כלי מדידה מתקדמים להערכת ביצועי קמפיינים, ניתוח DATA שיווקי, שיפור ביצועים על סמך נתונים וחיבור בין קמפיינים למערכות ניהול לקוח (CRM).  
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>וידאו מרקטינג </h2>
            <p class="blocfix">
                    הטרנד הלוהט בפרסום הדיגיטלי -  תכנון והפקת וידאו, שילוב סרטונים בקמפיינים פרסומיים וניהול והפעלה של ערוצי יוטיוב ומגוון פלטפורמות וידאו נוספות
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>אתרים ודפי נחיתה </h2>
           <p class="blocfix">
                    איך הכול התחיל ומה מחכה לנו בעתיד - היכרות עם ההיסטוריה של האינטרנט ועם הטרנדים החזקים ביותר ברשת, הקמה וניהול של אתרי מסחר (חנות אינטרנטית), אפיון אתרים ועבודה עם WordPress.  
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="what-block">
                <h2>ניהול לקוחות </h2>
             <p class="blocfix">
                    מול מי אנחנו עובדים בעצם - התנהלות מוצלחת מול הלקוחות, החל משלב תיאום הציפיות ועד לאמנות שימור הלקוח   
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<section id="after-section" class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="after-wrap">
            <div class="after-content">
                <img src="assets/images/after_icon.png" class="after-icon">
                <h2>מה יהיה לכם בידיים כשתסיימו את הקורס?</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>הסמכה מקצועית לעבודה בעולם הפרסום הדיגיטלי (בארץ ובעולם)</li>
                    <li class="yellow">ניסיון מעשי בעבודה מול לקוחות</li>
                    <li class="blue">תיק עבודות שישמש ככרטיס ביקור ללקוחות פוטנציאליים</li>
                    <li class="yellow">יכולת מעשית בתכנון וניהול קמפיינים בכל הפלטפורמות הדיגיטליות</li>
                    <li>שליטה מלאה בכלי מדידה, ניתוח וניטור של אפיקי הפרסום השונים </li>
                    <li>יכולת מעשית בכתיבה שיווקית וקופי דיגיטל</li>
                    <li class="blue">יכולת פיצוח בריף ובניית אסטרטגיה לקמפיין פרסום מ א-ת</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>

<section id="video-section" class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="video-bg">
            <h2 class="red"> עדיין לא סגורים? צפו בסרטון הבא והכירו את המנהל האקדמי של הקורס</h2>
            <div class="oembed">
                <div class="video-wrap">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dO7X2SIr5bA?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</section>

<section id="work-section" class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="work">
            <div class="img"></div>
            <h2>במה עובדים הבוגרים</h2>
            <p>בוגרי הקורס ישתלבו בקלות במשרדי פרסום ובחברות מסחריות שונות ויעבדו כמנהלי קמפיינים באינטרנט, מנהלי תוכן, מנהלי רשתות חברתיות, אנליסטים שיווקיים ומנתחי DATA, מנהלי אסטרטגיה שיווקית דיגיטלית ומנהלי פרויקטים בדיגיטל. הסטודנטים ירכשו גם ידע רב בניהול לקוחות, חשבונאות, מכירות ופרזנטציות ויוכלו להתניע קריירה כפרילנסרים, כשהאמת היא שקרוב למחצית מבוגרי המכללה לניו מדיה, עובדים היום כעצמאים</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<img src="assets/images/footer-divider.png" class="full-width">
<footer class="section" id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer-content">
            <h3 class="footer-h1">
                <img src="assets/images/footer-icon.png">
                ...ושלא תגידו שלא אמרנו לכם
            </h3>
            <h2 class="footer-h2">בסקר עדכני נמצא שהשכר הממוצע בתחום
                <br>
                השיווק הדיגיטלי בארץ הוא 13,450 ש"ח
            </h2>
            <div id="btn">
                <a href="#contact">
                    <img id="repons" src="assets/images/newbtn.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<a id="fixed" href="#">
    <img src="assets/images/openday.png" class="hide_mobile">
    <img src="assets/images/openday_m.png" class="show_mobile">
</a>
```

and this is the js code

```js
$('#form').on('submit',()=>{
    console.log('sending mail');
    validForm();
    return false;
});

let validForm = function(){
    let name = $('#name').val();
    let email = $('#mail').val();
    let phone = $('#phone').val();
    let check = $('#confirm').val();
    if(name !=='' && email !=='' && phone !=='' && check !==''){
        if(isNaN(name)){
                if (isNaN(phone) || phone.length !== 10) {
                }else{
                    if(isEmail(email)){
                        console.log('sending crm');
                        sendCRM(name,email,phone,check);
                        console.log('crm sent');
                        sendEmail(name,email,phone,check);
                        console.log('mail sent');
                    };
                };
            };
        };    
    };
   
let isEmail = function (email) {
    let regex =/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/igm;
    return regex.test(email);
};

let sendCRM = function(n,e,p,c){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.leadmanager.co.il/handlers/lm/submit.cms',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lm_form: 30754,
            lm_key: '59987823ef8749e7b9ec8a436aa9fe6d',
            name: n,
            phone: p,
            mail: e,
            open_day: c
        }
    }).done(function (r) {
        console.log('CRM OK');

    }).fail(function (r, x,y) {
        console.log('CRM fail');
    });
};
let sendEmail = function(n,e,p,c){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Mailer.php',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                name: n,
                phone: p,
                mail: e,
                open_day: c
            }
        }).done(function (r) {
            window.location.href = 'thanks.html';

        }).fail(function (r, x,y) {
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ThanksMail.php',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                name: n,
                phone: p,
                mail: e,
                open_day: c
            }
        }).done(function (r) {

        }).fail(function (r, x,y) {
        });
};
```

my problem is when i am testing the page in chrome and edge web browser i can see the details in the client crm system. but i get script error in explorer in line (1,26), in Firefox i have the same problem with this error message in the console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
None of the “sha256” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource. masterdigital
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]

any idea what is wrong whit this code?

Comment: Can you please add your error code?

Comment: error is Cross-Origin Request Blocked?

Comment: i did a test with all the propeller web browsers... after some adjustments i have a problem only in in explorer this is the console error i get :SCRIPT1002: syntax error form.js (1,26), the form is the js code you see in my post

Comment: no the error is script (1,26)

Answer (score 0):

i can see you using php as backend 
so you can add in  controller or function add this
or in starting of you page

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
```